# How to reduce Document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here a code contain a lot of  `document.getelementbyid` for simplify a list box for show and hide on on-click of radio button in JavaScript now am trying reduce the code but as a beginner of jquery learning on the way so kindly some one help to reduce this in jquery?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function fun(s) {
    /* table 1 */
    if (s == "maingroup") {
        document.getElementById("subgroup").value = null;
        document.getElementById("itemname").value = null;

        document.getElementById("subgroup_value").value = null;
        document.getElementById("itemname_value").value = null;

        document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("itemname").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
<script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/jZ6yE/)

Comment: `$("#id_here").val(value)` , `$("#id_here").css('propery', 'value')`

Comment: if any body  update my code its useful to learn from u all

Comment: @jagan  : Thats what dave has done

Comment: You should remove language attribute from script tag, it's deprecated, and type attribute is optional.

Comment: ya i got solution but i come up with other problem like onclick of radio button in jquery to display a listbox with autocomplete.how to do it...[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/dvx53/)

Answer (score 4):

```
 $("#subgroup,#itemname,#subgroup_value,#itemname_value").val('');
 $("#maingroup,#subgroup,#itemname").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sample-ID').val() ;

$('#sample-ID1').hide();

$('#sample-ID1').css('display','none');
```

Comment: No in my code i had done a  show and hide with removing a null value and i clear depend on click of radio button...so if u try to update code i will learn from now and future??

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this (now even smaller) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ6yE/12/))

You can use this JavaScript:

```
function fun(s) {
    var table = $('#'+s.parents('tr').data('id'));

    $('select,input[type=hidden]', table).val('').hide();
    $('#'+s.val()).show();
}

function fu() {
    $('select').hide();
}

$(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
        fun($(this));
    });
    fu();
})
```

With the following (cleaned up) HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr data-id='Table1'>
    <td><input type="radio" name="A" value="maingroup" /></td>
    <td>Main Group</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="A" value="subgroup" /></td>
    <td>Sub Group</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="A" value="itemname" /></td>
    <td>Item Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id='Table2'>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="country" /></td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="zone" /></td>
    <td>Zone</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="state" /></td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="city" /></td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="Areamanager" /></td>
    <td>Area Manager</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="B" value="outlet" /></td>
    <td>Outlet</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id='Table1'>
  <select id="maingroup">
    <option value="1">AA</option>
    <option value="2">BB</option>
    <option value="3">CC</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="maingroup_value" />
  <select id="subgroup">
    <option value="1">DD</option>
    <option value="2">EE</option>
    <option value="3">FF</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="subgroup_value" />
  <select id="itemname">
    <option value="1">GG</option>
    <option value="2">HH</option>
    <option value="3">II</option>
  </select>
</span>
<span id='Table2'>
  <input type="hidden" id="itemname_value" />
  <select id="country">
    <option value="1">JJ</option>
    <option value="2">KK</option>
    <option value="3">LL</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="country_value" />
  <select id="zone">
    <option value="1">MM</option>
    <option value="2">NN</option>
    <option value="3">OO</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="zone_value" />
  <select id="state">
    <option value="1">PP</option>
    <option value="2">QQ</option>
    <option value="3">RR</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="state_value" />
  <select id="city">
    <option value="1">SS</option>
    <option value="2">TT</option>
    <option value="3">UU</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="city_value" />
  <select id="Areamanager">
    <option value="1">XX</option>
    <option value="2">YY</option>
    <option value="3">ZZ</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="Areamanager_value" />
  <select name="outlet" id="outlet">
    <option value="1">aa</option>
    <option value="2">bb</option>
    <option value="3">cc</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="outlet_value" />
</span>
```

Comment: thanks for u r effort ..here it used by Tagname to hide and show and null but i need to do this by tag id only so how to do it??

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function fun(s)
{
       /* table 1 */

     if(s == "maingroup")
      {
         $("#subgroup").val('');
         $("#itemname").val('');

         $("#subgroup_value").val('');
         $("#itemname_value").val('');

         $("#maingroup").show();
         $("#subgroup").hide();
         $("#itemname").hide(); 
      }
<script>
```

Comment: k how to remove a null value and empty space is in listbox??

Comment: What do you mean by 'remove null value and empty space'?

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < out.length; i++)
   {
    //alert("Loop1" + i);
    if (out[i].innerHTML == "Null Value" || out[i].innerHTML == "")
    {
     document.getElementById("outlet").options[i] = null;
    }

   }
i have this code to remove if null value is present in listbox so like that how to remove in jquery??

Comment: Check this if($("#id").val() == '' || $("#id").val() == NULL) {$("#id").val(//set value)}

Answer (score -1):

For Using Jquery You'll need to import it in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

and your code'll be then:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#id").val(null); // for setting value
     $("#id").val(); //for getting value
     #("#id").css({
     "property":"value",
     }); //for .style
     });

<script>
```

Don't forget

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
//all js+Jquery.
});
```

Also you can use `$(".class") instead of $("#id")` if classNames are also unique.

Instead of `hide()` and `show()`.

Use `fadeOut('duration in millisecs')`, `fadeIn('duration in millisecs')` it'll add some magic.

and have a look at: [This.](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: its possible to update my code ..its useful to learn from u??